# How can I show an actionsheet above the Tab bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiactionsheet

IS it possible to display my action sheet above the Tab bar? If yes how can I do? Please advise me with an example?

I've tried the following code:
[actionsheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar]; but it doesn't reflect.

Note: I've set Tab Bar controller as Root Controller of my App.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't reflect"?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Those are useless words. Does the action sheet not display? Does it display but incorrectly? Does it crash? Be specific.

Comment: If u not wlling to answer just leave don't waste my time ok.

Comment: I'm trying to help. That's why I am asking you for more details. So far you have not told us what the actual problem is.

Comment: We have got the answer: [actoinsheet showInView:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]]; from a smart person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show action sheet above tab bar then just use below code

```
[actoinsheet showInView:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]];
```

Comment: I've tried it but still my actionsheet is just displayed over the tab bar but not above the tab bar. I want my action sheet to be shown above the tab bar.I mean default height of the tab bar is 49, I want my action sheet to be displayed above this 49.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to show action sheet above the tab bar because an action sheet always gets presented modally by the iOS. It gets displayed in the window's view hierarchy as a last subview object in case of iPhone/iPod. Hence as a model view it will always come above the tab bar. You can proceed with making your own actionSheet and present it in you view animated with the help of CAAnimation.

Comment: Nice really. Good Effort!I'll try it. Smart work. Thanks again!!